# pick required content from text file located on multiple remote servers and write to log in csv from where script is executed

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to read a text file from multiple remote servers and get required details from text file writing those details to csv log file creating on pc from where script is executed.
I want to add try, catch and if condition to get my script working as expected.
Requirement as below:

1. read file from remote server located under path,
2. replace unwanted characters ( which is being done by code -replace)
3. saving text file with set-content(already done)
4. get required content from file, store in a array variable(done)
5. write content in log file (.csv) created on PC from where the script is being executed.

Issue is script getting details, but when trying to write to log its not writing and giving error "Cannot index into a null array."

my code is below:

```
$servers = gc .\servers.txt
$Global:ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$date = (get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")
$ILOContent = "$ScriptDir\ILOConfigData_$date.csv"
Add-Content -Path $ILOContent -Value "ILO_Name,ILO_Domain,Network_Details,ILO-TimeZone,Directory_Users,LDAP_Directory_Authentication,Directory_Groups,SNMP-Settings,Directory_Server_Address"


Foreach($server in $servers){

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {

                    New-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG" -ItemType File -Name Current_ILOConfig.xml -Force| Out-Null
                    Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG"
                    $ILODataPath = Get-Location
                    $WantFile = "$ILODataPath\Current_ILOConfig.txt"
                    $FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
                    If ($FileExists -eq $True) {Remove-Item $WantFile }
                    Sleep(2)
                    Write-Host "Gathering current ILO configuration for $ENV:COMPUTERNAME" 
                    & "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\hponcfg.exe" /a /w `
                      "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\Current_ILOConfig.xml" |Out-Null
                    
                    Get-Content .\Current_ILOConfig.xml|Set-Content "Current_ILOConfig.txt"
                    Sleep(3)
                    $ILORAW_DATA = Get-Content .\Current_ILOConfig.txt

                    $ILORAW_DATA|ForEach-Object{
                                         $_ -replace '<!-- ' `
                                            -replace ' -->' `
                                            -replace '<' `
                                            -replace ' />' `
                                            -replace '"' `
                                            }|Set-Content .\Current_ILOConfig.txt

                    $ILO_DATA = Get-Content .\Current_ILOConfig.txt
                    Write-Host "Getting DNS details"
                    $DNS_NAME = $ILO_DATA |Where {$_ |Select-String -Pattern " DNS_NAME VALUE"," DOMAIN_NAME VALUE"}
                    $ILONAME = $DNS_NAME -split "="
                    $ServerILO = $ILONAME[1]
                    $ILONAME[3]

                    Write-Host "Getting Network details"
                    $NT = $ILO_DATA | where {$_ |Select-String -Pattern " IP_ADDRESS VALUE"," SUBNET_MASK"," GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS"," PRIM_DNS_SERVER VALUE", " SEC_DNS_SERVER VALUE"," TER_DNS_SERVER VALUE" } 
                    $Network = [array]$NT -join "`n"
                    $Network.Trim()

                    Write-Host "Getting ILO TimeZone"
                    $TZ= $ILO_DATA |Where {$_ | Select-String -Pattern " TIMEZONE VALUE"}
                    $TimeZone =$TZ -Split "="
                    $TimeZone[1]

                    #DIRECT
                    Write-Host "Getting Directory User details"
                    
                    $DIR_USER = $ILO_DATA |Where {$_ | Select-String -Pattern " DIR_USER_CONTEXT"}
                    $User =@()
                    
                        foreach($Usr in $DIR_USER)
                        {
                         $User += ($Usr -split "VALUE=")[1]
                          
                         }$User ; $DIR_USERS = [Array]$User -join "`n"

                    
                    Write-Host "getting Global:ScriptDir location"
                    Set-Location $Global:ScriptDir
                    Get-Location
                    $Data = $ILONAME[1]+$ILONAME[3]+$Network,$Model,$TimeZone[1],$DIR_USERS
                    $Data|Select-Object $ILONAME[1],$ILONAME[3],$Network,$TimeZone[1],$DIR_USERS |Export-Csv -Append -Path $ILOContent -notypeinformation                                                        

 }
 }
```

Example of the XML:

```
<!-- HPONCFG VERSION = "5.4.0.0" -->
<!-- Device: iLO 5  Firmware Version : 2.44  Firmware Date : 30-4-2021 -->
<RIBCL VERSION="2.0">
    <LOGIN USER_LOGIN="admin" PASSWORD="password">
        <RIB_INFO mode="write">
            <MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS>
                <ENABLE_NIC VALUE="Y" />
                <SHARED_NETWORK_PORT VALUE="N" />
                <VLAN_ENABLED VALUE="N" />
                <SPEED_AUTOSELECT VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <DHCP_GATEWAY VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_DNS_SERVER VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_WINS_SERVER VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_STATIC_ROUTE VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_DOMAIN_NAME VALUE="Y" />
                <DHCP_SNTP_SETTINGS VALUE="N" />
                <REG_WINS_SERVER VALUE="Y" />
                <REG_DDNS_SERVER VALUE="N" />
                <PING_GATEWAY VALUE="Y" />
                <IP_ADDRESS VALUE="100.11.13.65" />
                <SUBNET_MASK VALUE="255.255.255.255" />
                <GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS VALUE="100.11.13.1" />
                <DNS_NAME VALUE="server-ilo" />
                <DOMAIN_NAME VALUE="Contasa.com" />
                <PRIM_DNS_SERVER VALUE="10.110.21.73" />
                <SEC_DNS_SERVER VALUE="10.110.21.74" />
                <TER_DNS_SERVER VALUE="10.110.21.75" />
                <PRIM_WINS_SERVER VALUE="0.0.0.0" />
                <SEC_WINS_SERVER VALUE="0.0.0.0" />
                <SNTP_SERVER1 VALUE="" />
                <SNTP_SERVER2 VALUE="" />
                <TIMEZONE VALUE="Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi, Taipei, Perth" />
                <STATIC_ROUTE_1 DEST="0.0.0.0" MASK="0.0.0.0" GATEWAY="0.0.0.0" />
                <STATIC_ROUTE_2 DEST="0.0.0.0" MASK="0.0.0.0" GATEWAY="0.0.0.0" />
                <STATIC_ROUTE_3 DEST="0.0.0.0" MASK="0.0.0.0" GATEWAY="0.0.0.0" />
                <IPV6_STATIC_ROUTE_1 IPV6_DEST="::" PREFIXLEN="0" IPV6_GATEWAY="::" ADDR_STATUS="INACTIVE" />
                <IPV6_STATIC_ROUTE_2 IPV6_DEST="::" PREFIXLEN="0" IPV6_GATEWAY="::" ADDR_STATUS="INACTIVE" />
                <IPV6_STATIC_ROUTE_3 IPV6_DEST="::" PREFIXLEN="0" IPV6_GATEWAY="::" ADDR_STATUS="INACTIVE" />
                <IPV6_PRIM_DNS_SERVER VALUE="::" />
                <IPV6_SEC_DNS_SERVER VALUE="::" />
                <IPV6_TER_DNS_SERVER VALUE="::" />
                <IPV6_DEFAULT_GATEWAY VALUE="::" />
                <IPV6_PREFERRED_PROTOCOL VALUE="N" />
                <IPV6_ADDR_AUTOCFG VALUE="N" />
                <IPV6_REG_DDNS_SERVER VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_STATELESS_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_STATEFUL_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_RAPID_COMMIT VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_DOMAIN_NAME VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_SNTP_SETTINGS VALUE="N" />
                <DHCPV6_DNS_SERVER VALUE="N" />
                <ILO_NIC_AUTO_SELECT VALUE="DISABLED" />
                <ILO_NIC_AUTO_SNP_SCAN VALUE="0" />
                <ILO_NIC_AUTO_DELAY VALUE="90" />
                <ILO_NIC_FAIL_OVER VALUE="DISABLED" />
                <ILO_NIC_FAIL_OVER_DELAY VALUE="300" />
                <SNP_PORT VALUE="1" />
            </MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS>
        </RIB_INFO>
        <RIB_INFO mode="write">
            <MOD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS>
                <SESSION_TIMEOUT VALUE="30" />
                <ILO_FUNCT_ENABLED VALUE="Y" />
                <F8_PROMPT_ENABLED VALUE="Y" />
                <F8_LOGIN_REQUIRED VALUE="N" />
                <RIBCL_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <WEBSERVER_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <WEBGUI_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <REMOTE_CONSOLE_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <VIRTUAL_MEDIA_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <HTTPS_PORT VALUE="443" />
                <HTTP_PORT VALUE="80" />
                <REMOTE_CONSOLE_PORT VALUE="179" />
                <VIRTUAL_MEDIA_PORT VALUE="179" />
                <SNMP_ACCESS_ENABLED VALUE="Y" />
                <SNMP_PORT VALUE="161" />
                <SNMP_TRAP_PORT VALUE="161" />
                <SSH_PORT VALUE="21" />
                <SSH_STATUS VALUE="Y" />
                <SERIAL_CLI_STATUS VALUE="3" />
                <SERIAL_CLI_SPEED VALUE="1" />
                <VSP_LOG_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <MIN_PASSWORD VALUE="8" />
                <AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_LOGGING VALUE="3" />
                <AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_DELAY_SECS VALUE="10" />
                <AUTHENTICATION_FAILURES_BEFORE_DELAY VALUE="1" />
                <LOCK_CONFIGURATION VALUE="N" />
                <RBSU_POST_IP VALUE="Y" />
                <ENFORCE_AES VALUE="N" />
                <IPMI_DCMI_OVER_LAN_ENABLED VALUE="N" />
                <REMOTE_SYSLOG_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <REMOTE_SYSLOG_PORT VALUE="514" />
                <REMOTE_SYSLOG_SERVER_ADDRESS VALUE="" />
                <ALERTMAIL_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <ALERTMAIL_EMAIL_ADDRESS VALUE="" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SENDER_DOMAIN VALUE="" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SMTP_PORT VALUE="25" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SMTP_SERVER VALUE="" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SMTP_SECURE_ENABLE VALUE="Y" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SMTP_AUTH_ENABLE VALUE="N" />
                <ALERTMAIL_SMTP_AUTH_USERNAME VALUE="" />
                <PROPAGATE_TIME_TO_HOST VALUE="N" />
                <IPMI_DCMI_OVER_LAN_PORT VALUE="623" />
            </MOD_GLOBAL_SETTINGS>
        </RIB_INFO>
        <DIR_INFO mode="write">
            <MOD_DIR_CONFIG>
                <DIR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED VALUE="Y" />
                <DIR_LOCAL_USER_ACCT VALUE="Y" />
                <DIR_SERVER_ADDRESS VALUE="contasa.com" />
                <DIR_SERVER_PORT VALUE="3269" />
                <DIR_OBJECT_DN VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_1 VALUE="CN=ABC,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_2 VALUE="CN=XYZ,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_3 VALUE="CN=DDD,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_6 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_7 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_8 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_9 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_10 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_11 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_12 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_13 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_14 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_USER_CONTEXT_15 VALUE="" />
                <DIR_ENABLE_GRP_ACCT VALUE="Y" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT1_NAME VALUE="Administrators" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT1_SID VALUE="" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT2_NAME VALUE="Authenticated Users" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT3_NAME VALUE="CN=ABC,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT4_NAME VALUE="CN=XYZ,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT5_NAME VALUE="CN=DDD,DC=Contasa,DC=com" />
                <DIR_GRPACCT6_SID VALUE="" />
                <DIR_KERBEROS_ENABLED VALUE="N" />
                <DIR_KERBEROS_REALM VALUE="" />
                <DIR_KERBEROS_KDC_ADDRESS VALUE="" />
                <DIR_KERBEROS_KDC_PORT VALUE="88" />
                <DIR_GENERIC_LDAP_ENABLED VALUE="N" />
            </MOD_DIR_CONFIG>
        </DIR_INFO>
        <RIB_INFO mode="write">
            <MOD_SNMP_IM_SETTINGS>
                <SNMP_ACCESS VALUE="Enable" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_1_ROCOMMUNITY VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_2_ROCOMMUNITY VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_3_ROCOMMUNITY VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_1 VALUE="Server1.contasa.com" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_2 VALUE="Server1.contasa.com" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_3 VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_ADDRESS_3_TRAPCOMMUNITY VERSION="" VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_PORT VALUE="160" />
                <SNMP_TRAP_PORT VALUE="160" />
                <TRAP_SOURCE_IDENTIFIER VALUE="iLO Hostname" />
                <RIB_TRAPS VALUE="Y" />
                <OS_TRAPS VALUE="N" />
                <COLD_START_TRAP_BROADCAST VALUE="Y" />
                <SNMP_PASSTHROUGH_STATUS VALUE="N" />
                <WEB_AGENT_IP_ADDRESS VALUE="" />
                <CIM_SECURITY_MASK VALUE="3" />
                <SNMP_SYS_CONTACT VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_SYS_LOCATION VALUE="" />
                <AGENTLESS_MANAGEMENT_ENABLE VALUE="Y" />
                <SNMP_SYSTEM_ROLE VALUE="" />
                <SNMP_SYSTEM_ROLE_DETAIL VALUE="" />
            </MOD_SNMP_IM_SETTINGS>
        </RIB_INFO>
        <SERVER_INFO mode="write">
            <SET_HOST_POWER_SAVER HOST_POWER_SAVER="3" />
        </SERVER_INFO>
        <USER_INFO mode="write">
            <ADD_USER USER_NAME="admin" USER_LOGIN="admin" PASSWORD="%user_password%">
                <ADMIN_PRIV value="Y" />
                <REMOTE_CONS_PRIV value="Y" />
                <RESET_SERVER_PRIV value="Y" />
                <VIRTUAL_MEDIA_PRIV value="Y" />
                <CONFIG_ILO_PRIV value="Y" />
            </ADD_USER>
        </USER_INFO>
        <RIB_INFO mode="write"></RIB_INFO>
        <RIB_INFO mode="write">
            <SET_FEDERATION_MULTICAST>
                <MULTICAST_FEDERATION_ENABLED VALUE="No" />
                <MULTICAST_DISCOVERY_ENABLED VALUE="No" />
                <MULTICAST_ANNOUNCEMENT_INTERVAL VALUE="600" />
                <IPV6_MULTICAST_SCOPE VALUE="Site" />
                <MULTICAST_TTL VALUE="5" />
            </SET_FEDERATION_MULTICAST>
        </RIB_INFO>
        <SSO_INFO mode="write">
            <MOD_SSO_SETTINGS>
                <TRUST_MODE VALUE="DISABLED" />
                <USER_ROLE LOGIN_PRIV="Y" />
                <USER_ROLE REMOTE_CONS_PRIV="N" />
                <USER_ROLE VIRTUAL_MEDIA_PRIV="N" />
                <USER_ROLE RESET_SERVER_PRIV="N" />
                <USER_ROLE CONFIG_ILO_PRIV="N" />
                <USER_ROLE ADMIN_PRIV="N" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE LOGIN_PRIV="Y" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE REMOTE_CONS_PRIV="Y" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE VIRTUAL_MEDIA_PRIV="Y" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE RESET_SERVER_PRIV="Y" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE CONFIG_ILO_PRIV="N" />
                <OPERATOR_ROLE ADMIN_PRIV="N" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE LOGIN_PRIV="Y" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE REMOTE_CONS_PRIV="Y" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE VIRTUAL_MEDIA_PRIV="Y" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE RESET_SERVER_PRIV="Y" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE CONFIG_ILO_PRIV="Y" />
                <ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE ADMIN_PRIV="Y" />
            </MOD_SSO_SETTINGS>
        </SSO_INFO>
        <SERVER_INFO mode="write">
            <SERVER_AUTO_PWR VALUE="RESTORE" />
        </SERVER_INFO>
        <SERVER_INFO MODE="write">
            <SET_POWER_CAP POWER_CAP="0" />
        </SERVER_INFO>
    </LOGIN>
</RIBCL>
```

Comment: Your last two lines seem to be nonsense. Why would you create an array and try to select from it based on the the string literals you build the array with? Have you actually looked at what `$data` looks like and what the result for it would be after your select?

Comment: array created to get details from text file for a each particular item. Like, text file contains details for network(IP,subnet mask, default gate way and etc) which are in form of .xml and then array element will be written in log with correct details. log getting written on each remote server but I want the log on a location from where script is executed

Comment: first issue: data in log getting written on remote server, as soon as put below code ``` $Data = $ILONAME[1]+$ILONAME[3]+$Network,$Model,$TimeZone[1],$DIR_USERS
                    $Data|Select-Object $ILONAME[1],$ILONAME[3],$Network,$TimeZone[1],$DIR_USERS |Export-Csv -Append -Path $ILOContent -notypeinformation ```                                                       out of scriptblock , array holding values gets destroyed and null returns. Kinldy help here

Comment: Yes, that line is nonsense. Select-Object is meant to select the properties from an object. So naturally stuffing a bunch of data into an array and acting like that becomes an object doesn't work. Either directly export `$data` or a create a proper object. If you want to pull it out of your loop you will need to get it out of your Invoke-Command first. You could try to use [`$using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1#scope-modifiers).

Comment: could you please suggest on this please, how to do it?

Comment: First line `$x = null` in your invocation last line `$using:x = $data`. Alternatively return `$data`, write it to a file, simply output it on the console, send it by mail oder do a number of other things. Did you check what happens if you directly export `$data` or simply write it to a file rather than converting to a CSV?

Comment: Why are you creating (and treating) the XML file as TEXT??? (`Get-Content .\Current_ILOConfig.xml|Set-Content "Current_ILOConfig.txt"`) Use PowerShell's XML capabilities for this. Can you show such a ILOConfig.xml file in the question? and add an example of the desired CSV file?

Comment: converting xml file to text file because I want to remove special characters like "<!--" from XML file, once removed I saved the xml file as .txt to get content of network, Servername, Directory users and etc, storing only required data/value in array and then writting those array value in .csv file

Comment: Any chance of you posting a sanitized version of the **actual** XML ?

Answer (score 1):

As commented, I think it's a bad idea to parse properties from an XML file using textual methods.
Better let PowerShell parse it for you and pick the properties you need:

```
$date      = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")
$scriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  # or use: $PSScriptRoot
$outFile   = "$ScriptDir\ILOConfigData_$date.csv"
$servers   = Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt

$result = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host "Gathering current ILO configuration for '$server'" 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
        & "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\hponcfg.exe" /a /w `
          "C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\Current_ILOConfig.xml" | Out-Null
    
        # load the xml the hponcfg.exe just created (PowerShell will parse it for you)
        $config = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $config.Load("C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\Current_ILOConfig.xml")

        # preselect the nodes for MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS and DIR_USER_CONTEXT_1, DIR_USER_CONTEXT_2 etc.
        $networkSettings = $config.RIBCL.LOGIN.RIB_INFO.MOD_NETWORK_SETTINGS
        $userContext     = $config.RIBCL.LOGIN.DIR_INFO.MOD_DIR_CONFIG.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'DIR_USER_CONTEXT*' }
        # output a PSObject to be collected in variable $result
        [PsCustomObject] @{
            Server             = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            DNSName            = $networkSettings.DNS_NAME.VALUE
            DomainName         = $networkSettings.DOMAIN_NAME.VALUE
            IPAddress          = $networkSettings.IP_ADDRESS.VALUE
            SubnetMask         = $networkSettings.SUBNET_MASK.VALUE
            GateWay            = $networkSettings.GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS.VALUE
            PrimaryDnsServer   = $networkSettings.PRIM_DNS_SERVER.VALUE
            SecondaryDnsServer = $networkSettings.SEC_DNS_SERVER.VALUE
            TertiaryDnsServer  = $networkSettings.TER_DNS_SERVER.VALUE
            TimeZone           = $networkSettings.TIMEZONE.VALUE
            # join the UserContext values that are not empty with a NewLine (or any other character you choose)
            UserContext        = ($userContext.VALUE | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }) -join [environment]::NewLine
        }

    }
}

# remove the extra properties Invoke-Command added
$result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty "PSComputerName","RunspaceId","PSShowComputerName"
# save the result as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Result when opened in Excel:

[image]

Comment: output in csv file is incorrect by using above, kindly suggest

```
"Server","DNSName","DomainName","IPAddress","SubnetMask","GateWay","PrimaryDnsServer","SecondaryDnsServer","TertiaryDnsServer","TimeZone","UserContext","PSComputerName","RunspaceId","PSShowComputerName"
"server1",,,,,,,,,,"","server1","e1b9b89f-d37c-4a48-86af-38034e5b104b","True"
"server2",,,,,,,,,,"","server2","c2e0d661-716c-47e1-8245-d41e95fe6f9f","True"
"server3",,,,,,,,,,"","server3","5598744f-f437-405c-a6dd-a17f0e7c999f","True"
"Server4",,,,,,,,,,"","server4","6c47fb2b-dc35-4153-aa3e-8990a17b41db","True"
```

Comment: @PuneetTiwari Please edit your question and copy/paste the xml in there. Since you didn't give us that, I had to use some example I found on the internet and of course that will differ from yours..

Comment: As I am new in powershell and learning by designing different kind of scripts. May In know how i can implement Try-Catch-Finally in this script please? Also if a variable been used inside invoke-command scriptblock then how that variable can be used outside of scriptblock in this script?

Comment: @PuneetTiwari No, that is **NOT** the question here. If you're unsure you can reach the server from the list, then add a test as the first thing in the loop: `if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet)) { Write-Warning "Server $server cannot be reached" ; continue }` That's all; no need for try{} catch{}